# doxygen's call graph node order in the sequence of function calls

Tags: sequence, doxygen, call-graph

i want to analyze a large windows client project staticlly using doxygen. 
the call graph it produced with dot lists all caller nodes out of order.
is there any way to make the nodes ( top down ) in the order of calls sequentially just like the source code ?

Comment: How should it perform if the function is called multiple times? - E.g. `main() { function1(); function2(); function1(); }` . How would you want that to be rendered? The call graph this would produce is only going to have one arrow pointing from main to function1(). Would you want function1 to be above function2 since it is called first? Just wondering.

Comment: Maybe it is an option to generate the graph as svg file and edit it with a graphics programm like illustrator.

Comment: @Nick I would then suggest that function1 is drawn twice in the graph...